# Detect if record is new from Flow Designer

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

Is it possible to detect if a record, from a custom object, is new within the Flow Designer?

I have a process which executes an autolaunched flow and passes in the record id.

[image]

I then do a record lookup with decisions and actions thereafter.

I know it is possible to check if record is new within the process-builder by using `ISNEW()`, but using the same function within the flow designer gives me an error:

[image]

I see there is an `isDeleted` field available but no `isNew`:

[image]

I realize this is possible with an apex trigger on `insert` but am not super comfortable with apex just yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check that the Created Date and Last Modified Date for the record are the same. Though this solution assumes that you wouldn't be importing records into that object with a back dated Created Date.

If you are needing to import records with a back dated Created Date into that custom object, you could setup a checkbox and workflows for these records to flag when the record was created the first time, then unflag it when it was edited a subsequent time.

Comment: Great workaround! This worked, but in the end I decided to separate the record created and record modified logic into separate flows and trigger them with separate decisions in the process builder.